# tinymce custom-button replace content

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg, rte

I added a custom 'quote' button.

```
ed.addButton('blockquote', {
    title : 'blockquote',
    cmd : 'mceblockquote',
    image : url + '/img/blockquote.gif',
    onclick : function() {
        var blockquoteActive = tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.get('blockquote').isActive();
        if (blockquoteActive) {
             //replace <blockquote> tags ?!
             //set Button inactive       
        }
        else {
            ed.selection.setContent('<blockquote>' + ed.selection.getContent() + '</blockquote><br />');
        }
        }

});

ed.onNodeChange.add(function(ed, cm, n) {
    cm.setActive('blockquote', n.nodeName == 'IMG');
})
```

When I click the button, everything works fine. The selection is quoted.

- How do I replace the blockquote-tags when klicking the button again?
- How do I set the button inactive?

Regards,
saromba

Answer (score 3):

it worked thanks... 
I've made some changes (maybe / probably improvements).

When nothing is selected, do nothing

When text is already quoted

When user marked the text with a double-click, the blockquote element will now be removed

```
onclick : function() {
                var blockquoteActive = tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.get('blockquote').isActive();
                var selection = ed.selection.getContent();
                if (blockquoteActive) {

                   if (selection) {
                       var parElem = ed.dom.getParent(ed.selection.getNode(), 'blockquote');
                       var inner = parElem.innerHTML;
                       ed.dom.remove(parElem);
                       ed.selection.setContent(inner);
                   }
                   else return

                }
                else {
                    if (selection) {
                        ed.selection.setContent('<blockquote>' + ed.selection.getContent() + '</blockquote><br />');
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You may modify it a bit.

```
ed.addButton('blockquote', {
    title : 'blockquote',
    cmd : 'mceblockquote',
    image : url + '/img/blockquote.gif',
    onclick : function() {
        var blockquoteActive = tinyMCE.activeEditor.controlManager.get('blockquote').isActive();
        if (blockquoteActive) {
             //replace <blockquote> tags ?!

             content = ed.selection.getContent();
             content.replace(/<\/?blockquote>/ig,'');
             ed.selection.setContent(content);

             //set Button inactive

             // works only if blockquote is registered at the controlManager
             ed.controlManager.setActive('blockquote', false);

        }
        else {
            ed.selection.setContent('<blockquote>' + ed.selection.getContent() + '</blockquote><br />');
        }
    }

});
```